# Retrieve only positive integers from a given string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscharacterset

I have the following implementation where a `comboKey` is a string that I am trying to retrieve the integers.

For example if the `comboKey` is `2m1s` and then it returns `@[@"2",@"1"]`; which is perfect.

If `comboKey` is `0m2s` and then it returns  `@[@"0",@"2"];`, however I do not want to have `0`. I only want have positive number(s) `@[@"2"];`

```
+ (NSArray*)comboCategoryItems : (NSString*)comboKey
{        
  NSCharacterSet *nonDigitCharacterSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
  NSArray *outArray = [comboKey componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:nonDigitCharacterSet];
  outArray = [outArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length > 0"]];
  return outArray;
}
```

Comment: let me know for this string @"80m254s" what should return your method?

Comment: that would return 80 and 254, I am using string as a seperator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to do this, using regular expressions

```
NSRegularExpression * exp = [[NSRegularExpression alloc]initWithPattern:@"([1-9]([0-9])*)+" options:NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators error:nil];
NSString * text = @"80m254s";
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[exp enumerateMatchesInString:text options:NSMatchingWithoutAnchoringBounds range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult * _Nullable result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    [resultArray addObject:[text substringWithRange:[result range]]];
}];


NSLog(@"%@",resultArray);
```

for `@"0m2s"`

> 2017-07-15 22:31:18.576397 RegexTestingProject[21823:1942182] (
>       2 )

for `@"80m254s"`

> 2017-07-15 22:33:50.378485 RegexTestingProject[21826:1942829] (
>       80,
>       254 )

for `@"080m254s"`

> 2017-07-15 22:35:40.760626 RegexTestingProject[21828:1943403] (
>       80,
>       254 )

Hope this helps you

Comment: I am on my way heading to home, I will be testing it in 30-40 min. I have upvoted, once I check and then mark as answer. Is it ok?

Comment: @hotspring if solves your problem, I am glad to help, best regards

Comment: Any idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45125520/clicked-header-section-is-scroll-to-top

Comment: @hotspring i will review it

Comment: Thanks a lot @Reinier Melian

Comment: Why the downVote?

Comment: ok @hotspring anyway if works for your is ok then!, best regards by the way did you solve your other question?

Answer (score 1):

You you have done little bit mistake. In predicate you check string length rather than value. Just change the predicate like this `@"integerValue > 0"` your code will produce expected result.